# Stopping and resuming infinite loop on key input

Tags: java, loops, input, infinite-loop

Let's say we have an infinite loop, and we want to put it to sleep for a while, and then resume it. Instead of having a set time, we resume it when we press a key.

For example, in Java we could have:

```
while(true){
    doSomething();
}
```

Now, we could make this interruptable in many ways. We want to interrupt it on a key press, so we will have:

```
boolean running = true;
...
this.addKeyListener(this);
...
@override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    running = false;
}
```

And then run a method (let's say `run`), which contains:

```
while(running){
    doSomething();
}
```

But then we'd meet one problem: resuming.

So we take the `keyPressed` method, and change it's body to:

```
running = !running;
if(running){
    run();
}
```

There is just one problem here: the KeyListener won't do anything until the `run` method is finished. I've tried using threads, where we would have:

```
private class Runner implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

and in `keyPressed`:

```
if(running){
    runner.wait();
}else{
    runner.notify();
    runner.run();
}
running = !running;
```

but in my actual code the `doSomething` method is code that can't be interrupted (because it handles output to the screen), so `thread.wait()` can never be called (it will throw exceptions all the time and not actually wait).

So then, to summarize: How does one stop and resume looping something at will using key input in Java?

Comment: Could you show us what you tried with Threads ?

Comment: @Charlie I updated the post to contain that info

Comment: You should try `runner.start()` in keyPressed, this makes a parallel Thread, letting your original thread continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wait` and `notify` are intended to be called from different threads.  As the name implies, `wait` should be called in the thread which is paused and waiting to be notified that a condition has changed:

```
private final Object keyPressMonitor = new Object();

private boolean running = true;

private Runnable gameLoop = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            synchronized (keyPressMonitor) {
                while (true) {
                    while (!running) {
                        keyPressMonitor.wait();
                    }
                    doSomething();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO,
                "Interrupted; cleaning up and exiting.", e);
        }
    }
};
```

The other thread, presumably the AWT Event Dispatch Thread which is where your KeyListener (or Action invoked by an ActionMap/InputMap binding) is called, would *notify* the looping thread that the proper key has been pressed or released:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == theKeyICareAbout) {
        synchronized (keyPressMonitor) {
            running = true;
            keyPressMonitor.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == theKeyICareAbout) {
        synchronized (keyPressMonitor) {
            running = false;
            keyPressMonitor.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) for these purposes:

```
private static class Runner implements Runnable {
    private final AtomicInteger permits = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1, true);
    private volatile boolean running;

    public void putToSleep() {
        semaphore.acquireUninterruptibly();
    }

    public void resume() {
        semaphore.release(permits.getAndSet(0));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            semaphore.acquireUninterruptibly(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            semaphore.release(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            doSomething();
        }
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        //...
    }
}
```